# Find the domain where the solution of the initial value problems below is well-defined. $y'=\frac{-4x}{y} , y(0)=y_0>0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, solution-verification

Find the domain where the solution of the initial value problems below is well-defined.

$y'=\frac{-4x}{y} , y(0)=y_0>0$

My solution:

$y'=\frac{-4x}{y} \implies \frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{-4x}{y}\implies ydy=-4xdx\implies \int ydy=\int-4xdx$ $\implies \frac{y^2}{2}=-2x^2+c\implies y=\pm\sqrt{-4x^2+2c}$

$ y(0)=y_0 \implies c=\frac{y_0^2}{2}$

$y=\pm\sqrt{-4x^2+y_0^2}$ is the solution.

Find the domain:

$-4x^2+y_0^2\geq 0 \implies (y_0-2x)(y_0+2x)\geq0$

I got 2 solutions:

The first solution is $y=\sqrt{-4x^2+y_0^2}$ , the domain is $(0,\frac{y_0}{2}]$

The second solution is $y=-\sqrt{-4x^2+y_0^2}$ , the domain is $[-\frac{y_0}{2},0)$

Is my solution correct ?

Thanks !

Comment: The slope of your solution function is always negative.  However, for x<0, the differential equations says that the slope should be positive.

Comment: That's not to say your domain is incorrect, I just don't think the solution is quite right.

Comment: The answer seems right, but you need to write down how you get from $\ge$ to an open interval. $y$ can't be $0$.

Comment: @Andrei Now it's correct? Thanks!

Comment: Both solutions have the same domain. I am just uncertain if it's an open interval or a closed one. If it's a closed interval, $y'$ should probably be defined by the limit.

Comment: Note that $y_0>0$ so the second solution does not satisfy this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation can be rewritten as $$y(x)y'(x)=-4x=\left(\frac{y\cdot{y}}2\right)'(x),$$ which is equivalent to $$(y^2)'(x)=-8x.$$ By the fundamental theorem of calculus, $$\int_0^t(y^2)'(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=-4t^2=y(t)^2-y(0)^2,$$ hence $$y(x)^2=y(0)^2-4x^2.,$$ which implies $$y(0)^2-4x^2\geq0,$$ which implies $$x^2\leq\frac{y(0)^2}4.$$ This means the domain must be constrained to $\left[-\frac{y(0)}2,\frac{y(0)}2\right].$ This means $$y(x)=(-1)^n\sqrt{y(0)^2-4x^2},$$ with $n\in\{0,1\}.$ However, we know $y(0)\gt0,$ so $$y(0)=(-1)^n\sqrt{y(0)^2}=(-1)^n|y(0)|=(-1)^ny(0),$$ implying $1=(-1)^n,$ and thus $n=0.$ Therefore, the unique solution is $$y(x)=\sqrt{y(0)^2-4x^2}.$$ There is the caveat that $y$ is not differenitable at $-\frac{y(0)}2$ or $\frac{y(0)}2,$ so the domain gets restricted to $\left(-\frac{y(0)}2,\frac{y(0)}2\right).$